# code passes all the tests but fails in other tests.. please follow the link

Tags: python

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, ignoring sections of numbers between 6 and 7 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 7). Return 0 for no numbers.

```
sum67([1, 2, 2]) → 5    
sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7]) → 5
sum67([1, 1, 6, 7, 2]) → 4
```

my code:

```
def sum67(nums):
    total = 0
    n = 0
    while(n < len(nums)):
        if nums[n] == 6:
            while(nums[n] != 7 and n < len(nums)):
                n += 1
            n += 1
        if n > len(nums)-1:
            break
        total += nums[n]
        n += 1
    return total
```

[click here to test](http://codingbat.com/prob/p108886)

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises if there's a `6` directly after a `7`.

Your code detects the first `6` and skips forward past the next `7`. But if the next number is another `6`, it won't be skipped.

It'll work if you change `if nums[n]==6:` to `while n<len(nums) and nums[n] == 6:`.

Comment: The order of conditions need to be changed on the following line `while(nums[n] != 7 and n < len(nums))` as well, otherwise it will fail with input `[6]`.

Comment: @niemmi "every 6 will be followed by at least one 7"

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I totally missed that. In that case the second condition `n < len(nums)` is not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

@Rawing got this debugged properly. Here's another simple fix if you prefer:

```
def sum67(nums):
    total = 0
    n = 0

    while n < len(nums):
        if nums[n] == 6:
            # Skip forward until we find a 7 (or the end of the list).
            while n < len(nums) and nums[n] != 7:
                n += 1
        else:
            total += nums[n]

        # We're either looking at a number we just added to the total,
        # or we're looking at the 7 we just found. Either way, we need
        # to move forward to the next number.
        n += 1

    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Rawing pointed out your code doesn't cover the scenario where `6` follows immediately after `7`. Instead of having multiple loops and updating loop counter yourself you could just iterate over the numbers on the list and have extra variable telling if you need to skip them or not:

```
def sum67(nums):
    skip = False
    total = 0
    for x in nums:
        if skip:
            if x == 7:
                skip = False
        elif x == 6:
            skip = True
        else:
            total += x

    return total
```